# When to use client mode vs cluster mode in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, kubernetes, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

- Currently, we are deploying our application in docker images and Spark is being run within these containers. Clearly, there will be limitations to the resources available to Spark while running in  this format. Should we be using Spark on the host machines instead? How to handle networking in this case?
- Above application deployment will mean that Spark is used in client mode. Can we use cluster mode with this kind of setup to extend resources available to the jobs?
- Spark Setup - Standalone or via YARN / Kubernetes? Is standalone mode good enough for running intensive data processing jobs or should we use YARN/ K8 for this purpose?